# Need to create a jason request in lisp to send to a remote server

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i am new to lisp and want to send a jason request to a remote server. Can somebody help me on this? Below is the format that i want to send.

```
{
   "requestId":"12345",
   "houseNumber":"5555",
   "streetName":"Erling garden",
   "city":"PHOENIX",
   "state":"AZ",
   "unit":"",
   "floor":"",
   "building":"",
   "postalCode":"0000",
   "qualProcessType":"GGG",
   "network": "JINX",
   "SrcSystem": "BLUE"
}
```

I am formatting the message as such:

```
(defun format-msg (address loc hn)
   (declare (special *debug-level-2* *hostaname* *operator*
                     *der-type* *der-number* *ray-directory*))
   (let ((input-msg nil)
         (a-line nil)
         (city nil)
         (data nil)
         (config-stream nil)
         (id nil)
         (timeout nil)
         (state nil)
        )
      (when address
         (setq city (extract-city address))
         (setq state (extract-state address))
         (setq address (format-acs-address address))
         (setf config-stream
            (open (concatenate 'simple-string *ray-directory*
               "/config/info.config")
               :direction :input
               :if-does-not-exist nil))
         (unless (streamp config-stream)
            (debugger *debug-level-2*
                      "CONFIG FILE: info.config"
                      "CANNOT OPEN FOR READ"))
         (setq a-line (read-line config-stream))
         (when (equal (subseq a-line 0 9) "id:")
            (setf id (subseq a-line 10)))
         (setq a-line (read-line config-stream))
         (when (equal (subseq a-line 0 14) "timeout:")
            (setf timeout (subseq a-line 15)))
         (close config-stream)
       (when (not (equal (get-cala city state) " "))
         (setq input-msg (concatenate 'simple-string
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>
<WebRequest xmlns=\"http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema\"
xmlns:bim=\"http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/BIM\">
"
               "   <bim:RequestHeader>
"
               "      <bim:CorrelationId>"
                        *der-type* *der-number* *hostname*
                        (multiple-value-bind (s m h d mn y)
                           (decode-universal-time (get-universal-time))
                           (format nil "~2,'0d~2,'0d~2,'0d~2,'0d~2,'0d~2,'0d"
                           mn d y h m s ))
                        *operator* "</bim:CorrelationId>
"
               "      <bim:Flag>false</bim:Flag>
"
               "   </bim:RequestHeader>
"
               "   <RedemptionData>
"
               "      <Address>
"
               "         <bim:AId>" (get-cala city state) "</bim:AId>
"
                   (if hn
                      (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <bim:AssignedHouseNumber>"
                         (concatenate 'simple-string "HN-" hn)
                      "</bim:AssignedHouseNumber>
"
               "      <bim:DescriptiveLocation>"
                         (when (search "," (subseq address 1))
                            (subseq address 0 (+ (search ","
                               (subseq address 1)) 1)))
                     "</bim:DescriptiveLocation>
"
                   (if (setq data (search "RT " *street-name*))
                      (progn
                         (setq data (+ data 3))
                         (when (and (>= (length *street-name*) (+ data 1))
                                    (numeric-string? (subseq *street-name* data (+ data 1))))
                            (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <RuralAddress>
"
               "         <RuralRoute>" (subseq *street-name* data) "</RuralRoute>
"
               "      </RuralAddress>
")))
                      (when (setq data (search "BOX " *street-name*))
                         (setq data (+ data 4))
                         (when (and (>= (length *street-name*) (+ data 1))
                                    (numeric-string? (subseq *street-name* data (+ data 1))))
                            (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <RuralAddress>
"
               "         <POBox>" (subseq *street-name* data) "</POBox>
"
               "      </RuralAddress>
")))))
                     (concatenate 'simple-string
                      (when *street-number* (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <bim:StreetNumber>" *street-number* "</bim:StreetNumber>
"))
                      (when *street-name-prefix* (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <bim:StreetDirectionalPrefix>" *street-name-prefix* "</bim:StreetDirectionalPrefix>
"))
               "      <bim:StreetName>" *street-name* "</bim:StreetName>
"
                      (when *street-name-suffix* (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <bim:StreetDirectionalSuffix>" *street-name-suffix* "</bim:StreetDirectionalSuffix>
"))
                      (when *street-type* (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <bim:StreetType>" *street-type* "</bim:StreetType>
"))))
                      (when (get-loc-tier-type loc 3 t) (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <Unit>
"
               "         <bim:Name>" (get-loc-tier-type loc 3 t) "</bim:Name>
"
               "         <bim:Value>" (get-loc-tier-value loc 3) "</bim:Value>
"
               "      </Unit>
"))
                      (when (get-loc-tier-type loc 2 t) (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <Elevation>
"
               "         <bim:Name>" (get-loc-tier-type loc 2 t) "</bim:Name>
"
               "         <bim:Value>" (get-loc-tier-value loc 2) "</bim:Value>
"
               "      </Elevation>
"))
                      (when (get-loc-tier-type loc 1 t) (concatenate 'simple-string
               "      <Structure>
"
               "         <bim:Name>" (get-loc-tier-type loc 1 t) "</bim:Name>
"
               "         <bim:Value>" (get-loc-tier-value loc 1) "</bim:Value>
"
               "      </Structure>
"))
               "      <bim:City>" city "</bim:City>
"
               "      <bim:StateProvince>"
                         (cond ((equal state "IP")
                                  "ID")
                               (t
                                  state))
                      "</bim:StateProvince>
"
               "      </Address>
"
               "      <RequestType>SA</RequestType>
"
               "   </RedemptionData>
"
               "   <bim:SrcSystem>" id "</bim:SrcSystem>
"
               "   <bim:TimeOut>" timeout "</bim:TimeOut>
"
               "   <bim:TimeStamp>" (get-xml-date-time) "</bim:TimeStamp>
"
               "</WebRequest>")))
   input-msg)))
```

and, then i am creating a request message and sending it to the remote service, the request message is as such:

```
(setq json-data (remove #\newline (format-msg address loc hn)))
               (setq request-msg (concatenate 'simple-string
                  "POST http://" host service "

Host: " host "
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: " (symbol-to-string (length json-data)) "

" json-data))
```

I tried doing to send the lisp request with json data but i am getting this in response.

```
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/0.00.0.0</center>
</body>
</html>
")
"<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/0.00.0.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_I tried doing to send the lisp request with json data_" Where is that code? We can't guess what is wrong without seeing the code you are running.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an XML document as a request while using the `application/json` content type, I think there is some confusion here about which data format you actually need to send. Please refer to the documentation of the service you are trying to reach, and see if they provide examples (in a different language maybe). This will probably be more helpful to you. Don't hesitate to post back more information if you figure this out.

In the meantime, here are some advice that could help you with your code.

#### General remarks

First prepare your data in an internal format you like (lists, objects, etc.) and which makes sense in your application. Then, when you serialize, you can access your data and only change it to adapt it to your target format. But as you are doing now, you are kind of mixing the data construction and translation to XML. For example you read a configuration file and get the current date while writing the document. You could have two separate steps here.

Don't overuse `setq`, and more generally imperative constructs. When you open a file directly with `open`, you have a `close` call below but what if the code encounters an error between these two statements? then your stream is forever open. Prefer using abstractions like `with-open-file`.

Do not concatenate strings as much, this is what people do in Perl or other shell scripts but you can do better more easily in Lisp.

Finally, try using more readable names for your variables, this greatly helps when reading code.

#### XML

Suppose you want to write an XML document, then you should use the very good [CXML library](https://cxml.common-lisp.dev/quickstart.html). I'm assuming here you installed it with e.g. `(ql:quickload :cxml)` and that you have a package defined as follows:

```
 (defpackage :so-xml (:use :cl :cxml))
```

Then in this package:

```
 (in-package :so-xml)
```

You can write XML with macros:

```
(defun xml-template (&optional house-number)
  (with-xml-output (make-character-stream-sink
                    *standard-output*
                    :encoding :utf-8
                    :indentation 2)
    (with-namespace ("" "http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema")
      (with-namespace ("bmi" "http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/BIM")
        (with-element "WebRequest"
          (with-element "bim:RequestHeader"
            (with-element "bim:CorrelationId"
              (comment "TODO"))
            (with-element "bim:Flag"
              (text "false"))))
        (with-element "RedemptionData"
          (with-element "Address"
            (with-element "bim:AId"
              (comment "cala(city, state)"))
            (when house-number
              (with-element "bim:AssignedHouseNumber"
                (text house-number)))))))))
```

You can test that as follows:

```
> (xml-template "123")
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebRequest xmlns="http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema" xmlns:bmi="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/BIM">
  <bim:RequestHeader>
    <bim:CorrelationId><!--TODO--></bim:CorrelationId>
    <bim:Flag>
      false</bim:Flag>
  </bim:RequestHeader>
</WebRequest>
<RedemptionData xmlns="http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema" xmlns:bmi="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/BIM">
  <Address>
    <bim:AId><!--cala(city, state)--></bim:AId>
    <bim:AssignedHouseNumber>
      123</bim:AssignedHouseNumber>
  </Address>
</RedemptionData>
```

The first line defines a *sink* for the xml output, here I chose to output it directly to an output stream, with pretty-printing and `:utf-8` encoding.

Then, I define the two namespaces, by associating a prefix with a url.

The rest of the body are invocations to `with-element` and other constructs, which can be mixed with the usual Lisp code. For example, depending on whether `house-number` is NIL or not, some XML is conditionally emitted, thanks to `(when house-number ...)`.

The other advantage is that you can split your template function into separate components, this can be useful to manage complexity.

#### JSON

If instead you need to write Jason code, then you can use instead libraries like `yason` or `cl-json`. For example:

```
(defpackage :so-json (:use :cl :yason))
(in-package :so-json)


(let ((city "PHOENIX") (state "AZ"))
  (with-output (*standard-output* :indent 2)
    (encode-plist
     (list "requestId" "12345"
           "houseNumber" "5555"
           "streetName" "Erling garden"
           "city" city
           "state" state
           "unit" ""
           "floor" ""
           "building" ""
           "postalCode" "0000"
           "qualProcessType" "GGG"
           "network"  "JINX"
           "SrcSystem"  "BLUE"))))
```

The code above then prints the following JSON text:

```
{
  "requestId": "12345",
  "houseNumber": "5555",
  "streetName": "Erling garden",
  "city": "PHOENIX",
  "state": "AZ",
  "unit": "",
  "floor": "",
  "building": "",
  "postalCode": "0000",
  "qualProcessType": "GGG",
  "network": "JINX",
  "SrcSystem": "BLUE"
}
```